# Error 401 in angular even that I already Logged in

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hello guys I am working on an angular app that will fetch data from the server, but my problem is that it keep giving me 401 Error "unauthorized" the login API is working fine, but when I check the user it returns false.

```
$http({

        method: 'POST',
        url : 'localhost/login',
        params:{"login_name":"admin","password":"admin"},

    }).then(function success(response) {

     $scope.show= response.data;

        $http({ method: 'GET',
                url: 'localhost/checkUser',
                  }).then(function success(response) {
            $scope.show2=response.data;

        }, function error(response) {

        });
  });
```

Comment: Would be nice to know how authentication works at your backend. If it expects a cookie, then you need to ensure after the 1st call the cookie is returned properly to the FE and then it is being passed in the second call to the BE.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I need, but how can I Access to the cookies, its not found in the response. I can see it at the header though

Comment: go to your browser developer console, check request/response for the login call, if there is a proper auth token, then check request of the second call.